# 401 error with urbanairship using httpsurlconnection class

Tags: https, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am getting a 401 error when i try to hit the push URL. I am using HTTP BASIC authentication with "Application Key" as username and "Application Master Secret"as password. I am using JAVA HttpsUrlConnection class. I dont know whats wrong with my code.

```
 `            URL url = new URL("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push");
          HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setUseCaches(false);
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));

          String authString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
          authString = Base64Coder.encodeString(authString);
          connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+ authString);
          OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
          wr.write(data);
          wr.flush();

          int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

          //Get the response
          String responseLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())).readLine();`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your authString should be composed of `<application-key>:<application-master-secret>`. Also your authstring may not be getting encoded properly. Try using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or [ostermiller](http://ostermiller.org/utils/ostermillerutils_1_07_00.jar) library to encode the authstring

Comment: even after adding "ostermiller"lib in above code gives same error...any suggestions ??